# Selenium is breaking my page in IE11 when I set text

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer-11

I made some Automation tests with Selenium working on chrome, but now when I tried them in IE11 I got this weird behaviour: I land in a Page with a Search Box and a Search Button, pretty standard, and when I either *set(" ")* or *sendKeys(" ")* to an input textbox, the page "moves" to the left as is it had broken, imagine the page in the center of the screen and suddenly the left margin would dissapear and the page would stretch to the left... Does anybody know what I'm talking about?
Any help please?

BTW I also tried doing some actions in other elements and they won't break the page, also clicking the textbox won't do the trick, it happens when I put text in it

Comment: How about you provide some code and a reproducible scenario?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't give you a scenario :( I can't reveal any information involving this project. I just wanted to know if this was an issue with Selenium (if it had happen to someone before) or if it's my application that's broken when accessed with this controls. the application is made with Angular, if that's relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, "sendKeys" is likely what we call a "native event" and so it depends highly on the implementation of the binary driver for IE.   For example, Selenium only officially supports native events on Firefox up to version 31.0.6 and not versions 32+.  IE11 is pretty new and also comes in different versions (since it auto-updates).  So, if you need to do a sendKeys that is non-native (which is usually not necessary) then you can probably code one using a JavascriptExecutor object.   Let us know if that works for you.

-- addendum --
The Selenium team would tell you that they didn't want to include the javascriptExecutor funtionality in Selenium, but it is scenarios like this where the executor capability shows its true value.

Comment: I tried with JS and it sets the value without breaking the page! But it looks like it has some "keyPress" "keyUp" events that won't let me do the search if I set the value like that :( any other option?

Comment: Ok, I finally made it work with JS, there was some issues with Angular that wouldn't let me send the data, thanks!